# Insert data into DB by codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into a database but it doesn't work. It just catches data that I input via the form and shows on the URL bar.

Below in my view *input_data.php* it is located in: *C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\views\form\input_data.php*.

```
<form>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
        <fieldset>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label for="lettername" class="control-label pull-right">ឈ្មោះលិខិត/ខ្លឹមសារ</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input id="letter_name" size="50" name="letter_name" placeholder="ខ្លឹមសារលិខិត" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('letter_name'); ?>" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('letter_name'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label for="letternumber" class="control-label pull-right">លេខលិខិត</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input id="letter_number" size="50" name="letter_number" placeholder="លេខលិខិត" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('letter_number'); ?>" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('letter_name'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 text-left">
                    <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="បញ្ចូល" />
                    <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="លុបចេញ" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>'
```

Below is my model *login.php* located in *application\model\login.php* and table in the database is  *come_list*.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Login extends CI_Model {

    function add_letter($data){

    $this->db->insert('come_list', $data); 
    echo "user Added";
    }
}
?>
```

below is controller *Main.php*:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Main extends CI_Controller {
      public function index()
      {
      $this->load->view('form/input_data');
      }   

      public function insert_come(){
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

      //Validating Name Field
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('letter_name', 'ខ្លឹមសារលិខិត',  'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('letter_number', 'លេខលិខិត', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
           $this->load->view('form/input_data');
      }
      else
      {
           //Setting values for tabel columns
           $data = array(
                    'Name' => $this->input->post('letter_name'),

                    'Letter_Number' => $this->input->post('letter_number')
                );
                $this->load->model('login');
                     //Transfering data to Model
                $this->login->add_letter($data);
                //Loading View
                     $this->load->view('form/input_data');
               }
 }  
}
?>
```

Comment: You may use this tutorial https://www.formget.com/insert-data-into-database-using-codeigniter/

Comment: I have try to follow this but still not working. but if I download the file from this side, it work normally. and i try to find what different between them. after i change what i found it still not work.

Comment: I am showing you simple code Please wait .

Comment: Now it works thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think problem is in your action of form. Use this form

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>main/insert_come">
```

after ending form use

```
</form>
```

Comment: After I follow your instruct, when I enter data and click button submit it shows "404 Page Not Found"

The page you requested was not found. what should i continue?

Answer (score 0):

Post data will be available in model also, there is no need to send it from controller

```
      $this->Name    = $_POST('letter_name');
      $this->Letter_Number  = $_POST('letter_number')

      $this->db->insert('come_list', $this);
```

Comment: Controllers are the ones that receive the HTTP requests, communicate with models to get the data, send it to views to generate the HTML code and return the results to the web browser.

Comment: Yes, I agreed. Instead, $_POST can be used

Comment: Instead $_POST you should codeigniter way $this->input->post

Answer (score 0):

### Codeigniter Form

```
<?php if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)) echo $msg; ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('main/insert_come'); ?>" method="POST">
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
     <fieldset>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label for="lettername" class="control-label pull-right">ឈ្មោះលិខិត/ខ្លឹមសារ</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input id="letter_name" size="50" name="letter_name" placeholder="ខ្លឹមសារលិខិត" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('letter_name'); ?>" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('letter_name'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                        <label for="letternumber" class="control-label pull-right">លេខលិខិត</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input id="letter_number" size="50" name="letter_number" placeholder="លេខលិខិត" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('letter_number'); ?>" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('letter_number'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 text-left">
                    <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="បញ្ចូល" />
                    <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="លុបចេញ" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

> Controller main.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Main extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        }

        function insert_come()
        {

          //Validating Name Field
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('letter_name', 'ខ្លឹមសារលិខិត',  'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('letter_number', 'លេខលិខិត', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
               //$this->load->view('form/input_data');
          }
          else
          {
            $msg['msg'] = "";
            $letter_name = $this->input->post("letter_name");
            $letter_number = $this->input->post("letter_number");

            $data = array("Name" => $letter_name, "Letter_Number" => $letter_number);

            $res = $this->login->add_letter($data);
            if($res == 1)
            {
                $msg['msg'] = "Data added successfully into database" ;
            }
          }

          $this->load->view('form/input_data', $msg);
        }
    }
```

> Codeigniter Model login.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Login extends CI_Model {

    function add_letter($data=NULL)
    {
      $this->db->insert('come_list', $data); 
      $result =  $this->db->affected_rows();
      if($result == 1)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else
      {
        return FALSE ;
      }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank for your help. =)

Comment: Welcome @ChheangPhearum

Comment: Excuse me, I want to ask you a question. My input is unicode charater and mysql cannot understand the data. What can I do?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">  add this to your header in view

Comment: Another way to change database alter database 'Your bd' charset=utf8;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134839/discussion-between-aman-kumar-and-chheang-phearum).

Comment: @Aman Kumar sir why `$data=NULL` is used in this model function add_letter(`$data=NULL`){}??